# Loss of information while projecting multidimensional data

Tags: statistics, information-theory, dimensional-analysis

I'm interested in the evaluation of the loss of information after projecting multidimensional data. Since the dimensional reduction is a common tool to analyse data,a question about the loss of information seems to be reasonable, but I failed to find something useful, except comparing entropia before and after projection.

Can you help me and advice some technique?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you elaborate these in mathematical language?

Comment: In other words, if I have, for example, data from $\mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu},\Sigma)$ in d dimensions ($d\ge 3$), how much information do I lose after projecting my data on the plane (dim=2)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma)...